# Minimizing the Frobenius norm of a matrix involving the Hadamard product, $\|X(A\odot Y)-S\|_F$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Let $S\in\mathbb{R}^{L\times N}$ and $A\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}$ be known and arbitrary. I'd like to solve the following system:
\begin{align}
\min_{X\in\mathbb{R}^{L\times M},Y\in\mathbb{R}^{M\times N}} \frac{1}{2}\|X(A\odot Y)-S\|_F^2,
\end{align}
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product.

I've proceeded by defining $Z=X(A\odot Y)-S$ and then rewriting the objective function by $f=\frac{1}{2}Z:Z$, where ($:$) is the Frobenius product. Differentiating, we have
\begin{align}
\text{d}f&=Z:dZ\\
&=Z:\text{d}[X(A\odot Y)-S]\\
&=Z:[X\text{d}(A\odot Y)+\text{d}X(A\odot Y)-\underbrace{\text{d}S}_{=0}]\\
&=Z:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y+\underbrace{\text{d}A}_{=0}\odot Y)+\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]\\
&=Z:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y)+\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]\\
&=[X(A\odot Y)-S]:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y)+\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]\\
&=[X(A\odot Y)-S]:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y)]+[X(A\odot Y)-S]:[\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]\\
&=[X(A\odot Y)]:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y)]+[X(A\odot Y)]:[\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]\\
&\qquad-S:[X(A\odot \text{d}Y)]-S:[\text{d}X(A\odot Y)]
\end{align}

This is as far as I have been able to get. I know that I need to find the gradient of $f$ with respect to $X$ and $Y$ and then try to find a pair $(X^*,Y^*)$ that satisfies the two first-order conditions. I'm also aware that such a pair may not be unique (e.g., for any $c\in\mathbb{R}\not\cap\{0\}$, the pair $(cX^*,c^{-1}Y^*)$ is also a solution to this system), but I'm willing to overlook this for now, as I want to first characterize what a solution set would look like. I've done a search, but haven't been able to figure out whether operations of the form $X(A\odot Y)$ simplify nicely, so I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Is $\odot$ the Hadamard (entrywise) product?

Comment: Sorry, yes it is!

Comment: From the last step in the equation chain above, I've continued by rewriting the Frobenius product in its trace representation. Here is what I have now:
\begin{align}
\text{d}f&=\text{tr}\{X^\top X(A\odot\text{d}Y)(A\odot Y)^\top\}+\text{tr}\{\text{d}X^\top X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top\}\\
&\qquad-\text{tr}\{S^\top X(A\odot \text{d}Y)\}-\text{tr}\{S^\top\text{d}X(A\odot Y)\}
\end{align}

Comment: Here's another simplification (can find this by appropriately cycling the arguments of the trace functions above and rewriting in terms of the Frobenius product):
\begin{align}
\text{d}f&=[X^\top X(A\odot Y)]:[A\odot\text{d}Y]+[X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top]:\text{d}X\\
&\qquad-[S^\top X]:[A\odot\text{d}Y]-[(A\odot Y)S^\top]:\text{d}X.
\end{align}
Here, we can easily find the gradient of $f$ with respect to $X$ by treating $\text{d}Y=0$ and solving:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}&=X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top-(A\odot Y)S^\top.
\end{align}

Comment: However, I'm still unsure how to find $\partial f/\partial Y$ due to the nature of $A\odot\text{d}Y$.

Comment: Sorry, I got sloppy with my transposes in moving from the trace representation back to the Frobenius product in the simplification derived above. It should actually be
\begin{align}
\text{d}f&=[X^\top X(A\odot Y)]:[A\odot\text{d}Y]+[X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top]:\text{d}X\\
&\qquad-[X^\top S]:[A\odot\text{d}Y]-[S(A\odot Y)^\top]:\text{d}X.
\end{align}
Hence, the correct gradient of $f$ with respect to $X$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}&=X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top-S(A\odot Y)^\top.
\end{align}

I'm still struggling with $\partial f/\partial Y$. Any input is appreciated!

Comment: The rule for rearranging a Frobenius product is $$\eqalign{A:XY=AY^T:X\cr A:XY=X^TA:Y}$$ depending on which term you wish to move.  The rule for rearranging a Hadamard-Frobenius combination is $$A:(X\circ Y)=(A\circ X):Y$$ And within a Frobenius or Hadamard product, matrices commute $$\eqalign{A:X=X:A\cr A\circ X=X\circ A}$$

Comment: Thank you, @greg! I deduced the rule for rearranging the Frobenius product after my hiccup with it the first time around. The Hadamard-Frobenius combo you shared was unknown to me, but it seems obvious now :)

Using what you've shared, the differential is reduced to:
\begin{align}\text{d}f&=[A\odot\{X^\top X(A\odot Y)\}]:\text{d}Y+[X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top]:\text{d}X\\
&\qquad-[A\odot (X^\top S)]:\text{d}Y-[S(A\odot Y)^\top]:\text{d}X.\end{align}

So the gradient of $f$ with respect to $Y$ is
\begin{align}\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}=A\odot\{X^\top X(A\odot Y)\}-A\odot (X^\top S)\end{align}

Comment: The two gradients together are:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}&=X(A\odot Y)(A\odot Y)^\top-S(A\odot Y)^\top\\
&=[X(A\odot Y)-S](A\odot Y)^\top\\
&=Z(A\odot Y)^\top
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}&=A\odot\{X^\top X(A\odot Y)\}-A\odot (X^\top S)\\
&=A\odot\{X^\top[X(A\odot Y)-S]\}\\
&=A\odot(X^\top Z).
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\bp{{\boldsymbol +}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
$In addition to $Z,\,$ it will prove convenient
to define the matrix $W$ as
$$\eqalign{
W &= A\odot Y \qiq Z=XW-S \\
}$$
Set the two gradients (that you calculated in the comments) to zero,
and use pseudoinverses to solve them independently
$$\eqalign{
\grad{f}{X} &= ZW^T=\LR{XWW^T-SW^T}\doteq 0&\qiq X=SW^\bp \\
\grad{f}{Y} &= A\odot(X^TZ)=A\odot\LR{X^TXW-X^TS}\doteq 0&\qiq W=X^\bp S \\
}$$
Alternating Least Squares (ALS) can be used
to solve for the optimal $(X,W)$ matrices
$$\eqalign{
X_{k+1} = SW_k^\bp
,\qquad W_{k+1} = X_{k+1}^\bp S
,\qquad k = {k+1}
\\
}$$
Using random $(A,S)$ matrices of various $(L,M,N)$ dimensions and random initializations for $(X_0,Y_0)\;$ I observed the following behavior:

---

$\qquad$If $\,M\ge\min(L,N)\,$ then the iteration converges
in a single step.

$\qquad$In this case, $f\approx 0$ and both gradients $\approx 0$

$\qquad$If $\,M<\min(L,N)\,$ then the iteration converges
after a few dozen steps.

$\qquad$In this case, $f>0$ but both gradients $\approx 0$

---

Like Non-negative Matrix Factorization (NMF), the factors $(X,W)$ are not unique. Each $(X_0,W_0)$ leads to a different minimum and finding the *global* minimum is NP-hard.

---

This similarity to NMF suggests another idea,
i.e. Lee-Seung iteration
$$\eqalign{
X_+ = X\odot\fracLR{SW^T}{XWW^T}
,\qquad W_+ = W\odot\fracLR{X^TS}{X^TXW}
}$$
This iteration uses element-wise division and avoids calculating the pseudoinverse at each step. Each step is inexpensive, but it converges **very slowly**, often requiring thousands of iterations.

However, Lee-Seung iteration does confer control over the structure of the $(X,W)$ factors, i.e. any zero element of $X_0$ will create a corresponding zero element in the final $X$ factor. This can be used to generate upper/lower triangular factors.

Element-wise positivity (or negativity) of the factors can be  controlled in a similar fashion. Likewise column (or row) normalization constraints can be imposed on one of the factors at each iteration.

Comment: in the ALS formulas for $W = X^+ S$, do you mean $X^+ = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ ?

Comment: @MathLearner If $(X^TX)^{-1}$ exists, then yes.  Otherwise you'll have to calculate the pseudoinverse using an SVD-based method.

Answer (score 0):

@ A.P. , your two equalities are correct. The first one is clear $(X(A\circ Y)-S)(A^T\circ Y^T)=0$ but the second one is less clear. Indeed,  the rule for rearranging a Hadamard-Frobenius combination is absolutely not obvious. We can reason as follows:

For every $K\in M_{M,N}$, $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial Y}:K\rightarrow tr((X(A\circ Y)-S)(A^T\circ K^T)X^T)=0$
, that is $tr(X^T(X(A\circ Y)-S)(A^T\circ K^T))=0$.

Let $U=\{(i,j)|a_{ij}=0\}$; then $(A^T\circ K^T)_{ji}=0$ when $(i,j)\in U$ and, when $K$ varies, the indices $(j,i)$ s.t. $(i,j)\notin U$ are free. It is not difficult to see that $(X^T(X(A\circ Y)-S))_{k,l}=0$ when $(k,l)\notin U$ and is free when $(k,l)\in U$. That is equivalent to $A\circ (X^T(X(A\circ Y)-S))=0$.

Note that if $A$ has no zero entries, then to find $Y$ is equivalent to find $A\circ Y$; then we put $T=A\circ Y$ and the problem reduces to find $\inf_{X,T}||XT-S||^2$. It is equivalent to search the best approximation of $S$ by a matrix with rank $\inf(L,M,N)$; the standard method is to calculate  the SVD of $S$. Thus, I am not sure that the gradient method is the best one.

When $A$ has zero entries, then the problem reduces to find $\inf_{X,T}||XT-S||^2$ under the condition $t_{ij}=0$ when $(i,j)\in U$.